# Load CSV data via Ajax for display in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv, highcharts

I am having problems loading some external CSV data via Ajax into Highcharts.
It's especially the step of passing the returned values into Highcharts which I don't get...

The first function loads the data:

```
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xxx",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) 
        {
            var series_return = processData(data);

            // like this???
            //chart.addSeries({
            //  name: "NPP",
            //  data: series_return
            //});                       
        }
    });
};
```

The data are being processed here, as the first couple of lines contain only text:

```
function processData(allText) 
{
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var lines = []; var n = 0; var series_return = [];

    for (var i=1; i<allText.length; i++) 
    {
        if (allTextLines[i])
        {
            if ((allTextLines[i].substring(0,2) == "19") || (allTextLines[i].substring(0,2) == "20"))
            {
                n++;
                series_return[n] = allTextLines[i];
            }
        }                   
    }

    return series_return;
}
```

The data look like this then:

```
[1: "2015/12/01,15.0,-90.0,0.11532234042553188", 2: "2015/11/01,15.0,-90.0,0.10756382978723407"]
```

The Highcharts script:

```
// ---------------------------------------------------
// ---------------      Highcharts     ---------------
// ---------------------------------------------------

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(
    {
        chart: 
        {
            renderTo: 'div_graph',
            defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
            marginLeft: 120,
            marginTop: 100,
            events: {
                load: requestData
            }
        },
        xAxis: 
        {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            gridLineDashStyle: 'Dot',
            tickWidth: 0,
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: 
        {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            gridLineDashStyle: 'Dot'
        },
        plotOptions: 
        {
            series: 
            {
                connectNulls: false,
                shadow: false,
                lineWidth: 2,
                color: '#3f9aff',
                marker: 
                {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },  
        series: [{
            name: 'NPP',
            data: []
        }]
    });
});
```

So, what is the correct way of passing the data over to Highcharts? I looked quite around, and tested things here and there, but in vain.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Which values should be printed as y? The problem is that you push a strings into array, instead of numbers. Use parseFloat(), like series_return[n] = parseFloat(allTextLines[i]);

Comment: Yep, that was a fault of mine, shame on me. Didn't saw the tree in the forest - it should take the first and the fourth value for x and y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to change your `processData` function to end up with an array of arrays. Your datestring should be a date or a timestamp, your numberstring a real float, like this:

```
data = [
    [new Date("2015/12/01,15.0").getTime(), parseFloat(-90.0)],
    // ...
];
```

then, you can pass your data to highcharts.

Also, it seems that highcharts offer [a module to deal with csv data](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module). Have you had a look at it ?